# IIS 7 request duration monitoring

Tags: performance, iis, powershell, monitoring

i am curious if there is a way of monitoring the request duration time on an iis server. Personally I have came up with a solution but it's really resource intensive and that is why i'm asking the question, just to gather more opinions.

My plan is to extract the duration time of each request and send it to graphite so as to have a real time overview of the performance of the webserver. The idea i've came up with is to use poweshell with its webadministration module. And if you run  `get-item IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool | Get-WebRequest` for example you get all the requests on that app pool with a lot of info including the time info.

The thing is that i should have a script which runs every 100 ms to get all requests and that is kinda wasteful. Is there a way to tell iis to put the request duration time(in miliseconds) in the logs? Because then it would be much easier to get the information I need.

Comment: did you tried using `Get-WebRequest` ? https://powershell.org/forums/topic/selectively-kill-a-specific-request-under-an-app-pool/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is such a feature on IIS, but I've done the same (sending iis page times to graphite) by using a reverse proxy between internet and the iis server, like nginx.

The [proxy module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) from nginx allow you to log on each request the time the backend took to produce the page.

Also, having a proxy like [nginx](http://nginx.org) in fron of an IIS could be very helpful if you have to deal with visits with slow connections, nginx will store the reply from backend, drop backend connection and wait until visitor gets all the content. Highly recommended.

In case you go this route, you should use [logster](https://github.com/etsy/logster) (also from etsy guys) or [logstash](http://logstash.net/) to parse nginx logs each period of time you want (likely every minute).

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there is a feature that logs requests based on a regex, and it's called Advanced Logging Module. You can specify from a number of fields what you want to get loged and it's W3C compliant. In my case i had time take as a filed which can be specified and that was what i was looking for. After that i written a script in powershell which parses the logs and gets the information i need, constructs a metric and sends it to statsd which in term sends it to powershell.

The method i chose for the log parsing was the following: in the script i used get-content comandlet from powershell to gather all the logs in one file(yes iis breaks the logs in multiple files, and i'm guessing the number of logs is dependent on the number of your working processes but i'm not sure). This was the first iteration in a second iteration i gather all the logs in another file and make a diff between the first file and the latter and only the difference gets processed.

I chose this method because it's i thought it wold be better to have the minimum regex processing. The next step is erasing the first file of accumulated logs and moving the second one in pace of the first that was erased and running the script again, so to have always a method of comparison. Also the log rollover is at one hour, after which the logs are erased.